# Is there a way to store multiple dates into a table with potential to grow?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table like this in `SQLITE3`:

[image]

I need to query this table by `ID|DOC_ID|TRANS_DOC_ID` and most importantly by `DATE` because I need to get the data day by day. ex: `TODAY|YESTERDAY|ETC`

So far the query is easy, as I can just do this to get the rows by day:

`SELECT * FROM CLIENTRECORD WHERE DATE = '2020-12-01'`

The problem is when I need to display specific records on other dates:

ex: I have a row with `DATE` `2020-12-01` but I also want it displayed on `DATE` `2020-01-01` or maybe `2020-01-02`, etc. What do I do in this situation? and so I thought about adding another col as `DATES` which was supposed to be an array of comma-separated dates BUT I researched that this is a BAD solution, I also thought about adding a separate TABLE just for dates but since the dates aren't fixed (they might contain 1 date or maybe even 10 who knows), I am confused as to what I am supposed to do.

The end goal is that a row may or may not contain more than 1 date, would look something like this if I want to query for the row with or without multiple dates:

`SELECT * FROM CLIENTRECORD WHERE DATE = '2020-12-01' OR DATES LIKE '2020-12-01'`

something similar to it.

Comment: "I want to display specific records on other dates".  Well, include those dates in your `where` clause.  I'm a bit confused on what you are asking.

Comment: no, I need to link the row to other dates, what I am trying to say is that a row might to may not contain more than 1 date.

Comment: Isn't your problem solved with `WHERE DATE IN ('2020-12-01', '2020-12-02', ....)`? You must clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas As I said before I wanted a row to contain more than 1 date but don't know how to insert more than 1 date into a row. Is there something I am not explaining well? please let me know. the `DATE` field can not contain more than 1 date so I tried to use `DATES` field but I am not sure if this is ideal or even how to query it afterward since a row can contain more than 1 date, how many? don't really know as user can add as many dates as he wants.

Comment: Create another table with 2 columns: a column that will be the reference to the primary key of the current table and a date. So if a row in your current table needs 10 dates you will have 10 rows in the new table with the same value for the 1st column and the 10 dates for the date column. When you need to query your current table you will simply join it to the new table and the link will be the primary key of the current table and the 1st column of the new table. Read this: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/

Comment: "I have a table like this" please show that as a MRE as described in the tag info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info